# Angular CLI - Please add a @NgModule annotation when using latest

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angularjs-ng-model

**note:** I'm new to Angular, so please excuse any new comer stupidity here.

**Details**

- I've installed the latest version of Angular CLI
- The default app loads and runs perfectly fine after 'ng serve'

**Issue**

- I decided to create a new module an import it into the app module
- This is something I've done a couple of times in Angular 2 and it's worked perfectly fine
- However, since I ran the latest version of Angular CLI this morning, importing a module breaks and I receive the following error:

> compiler.es5.js:1689 Uncaught Error: Unexpected directive 'ProjectsListComponent' imported by the module 'ProjectsModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

**App Module**

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { ProjectsModule } from './projects/projects.module';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    ProjectsModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase, 'AngularFireTestOne'), // imports firebase/app needed for everything
    AngularFireDatabaseModule, // imports firebase/database, only needed for database features
    AngularFireAuthModule // imports firebase/auth, only needed for auth features
  ],

  declarations: [AppComponent],

  bootstrap: [AppComponent]

})

export class AppModule { }
```

**Projects Module**

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ProjectsListComponent } from './projects-list.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({

    declarations: [
        ProjectsListComponent
    ],


  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ProjectsListComponent,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      { path: 'projects', component: ProjectsListComponent }
    ])
  ]
})

export class ProjectsModule { }
```

The process I've taken to setting the module up hasn't been any different to when I was using Angular 2. However, after having issues with compatibility between Angular Cli, firebase and angular fire, I decided to get the latest of everything this morning.

Any help with this one would be massssssively appreciated as I've hit a brick wall with my understanding of it all.

Thank you.

Comment: why are you using a project module ?

Comment: Hi Rahul. I plan to build a solution with components related to projects and components related to issues. I plan to segregate those into a "ProjectsModule" and an "IssuesModule". In this initial test, I got as far as adding my "ProjectsModule" only to find it doesn't work as usual...

Comment: Try to import the   'ProjectsListComponent' into your App Module under declarations

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The problem is the import of `ProjectsListComponent` in your `ProjectsModule`. You should not import that, but add it to the export array, if you want to use it outside of your `ProjectsModule`.

Other issues are your project routes. You should add these to an exportable variable, otherwise it's not AOT compatible. And you should -never- import the `BrowserModule` anywhere else but in your `AppModule`. Use the `CommonModule` to get access to the `*ngIf, *ngFor...etc` directives:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
     ProjectsListComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(ProjectRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
     ProjectsListComponent
  ]
})

export class ProjectsModule {}
```

**project.routes.ts**

```
export const ProjectRoutes: Routes = [
      { path: 'projects', component: ProjectsListComponent }
]
```

Comment: Hi Pierre, thank you so much for such a detailed response. What's 'AOT compatible'? (if you don't mind answering that here) ...(I can accept the answer in two minutes :) )

Comment: AoT = Ahead of Time (https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler). In-lining (not breaking into exportable pieces) will prevent angular from being able to perform AoT - which means you will miss out on the big performance gain that AoT gives @MegaTron

Comment: Works in Angular 8.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I created a new ChildComponent in Parentcomponent whereas both in the same module but Parent is registered in a shared module so I created ChildComponent using CLI which registered Child in the current module but my parent was registered in the shared module.

So register the ChildComponent in Shared Module manually.