# Unexpected value 'MatBottomSheet' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio, angular-material, angular8

I'm very new to programming.trying to implement Angular MatBottomSheet. but getting above error.
added angular material. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szTgP.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check this also [Angular CLI - Please add a @NgModule annotation when using latest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44777457/angular-cli-please-add-a-ngmodule-annotation-when-using-latest/44777563)

pass your MatBottomSheet **Export** and **Declarations**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
     MatBottomSheet
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(ProjectRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
     MatBottomSheet
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to share with us the code of your modules.

But firstable try to export the MatBottomSheet from your module.